# Get object from form with errors in play framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am getting an error when I try to extract a user from a form with validation errors.

I have the following route configured in my `routes` file:

```
GET     /users/:user            controllers.UsersController.viewUser(user: models.User)
GET     /users/:user/edit       controllers.UsersController.editUser(user: models.User)
```

This is fine at this point, and I can render a link to the user view from my scala templates:

```
routes.UsersController.viewUser(myUserObject)
```

My problem is that in my user edition form I need to get `myUserObject` from a `Form[User]` object. What I am currently doing is:

```
routes.UsersController.viewUser(userForm.get)
```

However, when the `userForm` has any errors, the `get` method raises an exception, as shown in [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/api/java/play/data/Form.html#get).

The approach I have taken is passing an additional `User` parameter to the scala view, together with the `Form[User]` parameter I was passing up to now, I mean,

```
userEdit.render(user, userForm)
```

instead of just

```
userEdit.render(userForm)
```

However, I would like to know if there is a more suitable solution that does not involve including an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#fill-values) states that you can prefill a form with existing data:

```
val filledForm = userForm.fill(User("Bob", 18))
```

Given the preexisting `User`, it should be trivial to adapt to your example.

Comment: After the validation error the form should be filled with the information entered by the user, not the information already persisted in database. Would this instruction overwrite the information entered by the user?

Comment: I think so, but you could just fill the form with the user data when the form contains errors. Rather than doing a `userForm.get`, you should have a look at `userForm.fold`. In this case you need to explicitly deal with the case that the user entered incorrect data